# WP8 toolkit contextMenu item not selected on hold

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit

have a little problem with my ContextMenu, some times the item is not selected in the LongList when the ContextMenu is clicked, this gives me the problem that i do not know what item the user have clicked. If i cickly click the item first and then hold for the Context Menu dose it work, but how can i make this work every time the user click and holds?

Here is my xaml

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="List"
                        Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"
                        Height="470" Tap="List_OnTap">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}">
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="false">
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Add as favorit" 
                                              Click="AddFavorite" />
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

And my code behind

```
private void AddFavorite(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemViewModel obj = List.SelectedItem as ItemViewModel;
    if (obj == null) return;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page.xaml?id=" + obj.Id + "&fav=true", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the item from the ContextMenu itself. The menu has it's DataContext set to the element that is being bound to. Simply get the DataContext and you're off!

```
private void AddFavorite(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    ItemViewModel obj = element.DataContext as ItemViewModel;
    if (obj == null) return;

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page.xaml?id=" + obj.Id + "&fav=true", UriKind.Relative));
}
```